# In Vue js build app.js file showing file path

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack

Build app.js file showing file path details. The build file comes with file path and other information, which is pasted below.

Seems like a configuration issue.

Any help much appreciated.

```js
{path:"C:\\Users\\o885535\\test\\sample\\src\\commons\\constants.js",statementMap:{0:{start:{line:1,column:18},end:{line:137,column:1}}},fnMap:{},branchMap:{},s:{0:0},f:{},b:{},_coverageSchema:"43e27e138ebf9cfc5966b082cf9a028302ed4184"},o=l[s]||(l[s]={});return o[e]&&o[e].hash===n?o[e]:(i.hash=n,o[e]=i)}(),J=(W.s[0]++,
```

Comment: You didn't really show your configuration, especially for webpack.
My guess would be that you should set a webpack to production mode and remove any debug functionality.

Comment: Are you using `vue-cli`?  If not, can you post your `webpack` config?? Going to need some more info to assist... Help us help you...

Comment: @MattOestreich , yes using vue-cli

Comment: Please provide us with your `app.js` file as well as your `vue-config.js` file if you have one and your scripts object inside package.json.

Comment: also, how are you getting your built file? (which is the command)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of some permission problem on disk C:, you can try to move your project to other disk and rebuild it.